# Why do the words change between Inkspell and Inkdeath?

Tags: inkheart-trilogy

I've just finished *Inkdeath* for the second time and I noticed something that bugged me.  Let me explain what happens.

In Inkspell:

> The Bluejay binds the White Book for the Adderhead, but it because of Fenoglio's words, if three words are written in the book, whoever's name is in the book will lose their immortality.  These three words are "heart", "spell" and "death"

(Note, I am citing the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_trilogy#Inkspell), but I am sure this is what is says in the book and I will keep searching through it to verify this)

In Inkdeath:

> The three words the Bluejay writes in the book are "Heart", "Blood" and "Death" (end of the chapter *The Box*)

Now, the words from *Inkspell* make sense, as it ties in with the title of the books in the trilogy, so I assumed that was the reason, yet reading *Inkdeath* shows a change.

What I would like to know is ***why*** there was a change in the words with no reference to there being any such change in the books.

I know these books are originally written in German, so perhaps there was a translation error?  If not, has Funke addressed this discrepancy at all?  I would naturally prefer an in-universe answer, but I doubt that exists, having just read the books, so an out-of universe answer, which seems most likely to me, will be acceptable also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a translation issue.

The books themselves in the original German are named *Tintenherz*, ***Tintenblut*** and *Tintentod* which directly translate to *Inkheart*, ***Inkblood*** and *Inkdeath*, which does make better sense thematically than Heart, **Spell** and Death.

So it seems that the translation in *Inkspell* was made without considering that the words in the book were supposed to reflect the titles of the trilogy, but when it because clear that this was the case, the translation of the Words of Power was changed to reflect this.

I would suspect that later reprints of *Inkspell* might also reflect the updated Words of Power.

ETA: This seems to be a first print issue. I was finally able to check this out in my copy of Inkspell, a Chicken House / Scholastic reprint dated January 2006 (first American edition is October 2005) and the words are consistent with the English book titles.

> *But there was that one thing the girl did not tell the Adderhead: The
>   book not only made him immortal but could kill him, too, if someone
>   only wrote three words on its white pages, and those words were:
>   heart, spell, death.*
>   - Chapter 59, The Adderhead, Inkspell

and

> *Mo clutched the pencil in his fingers and opened the White Book...
>
>   HEART.
>
>   Mo’s fingers shook as he traced each letter...
>
>   Keep looking up, Mo, or he’ll realize that you’re writing...
>
>   SPELL.
>
>   Only one more word now. A single word.
>
>   The Piper glanced at him. He looked at the open book. Mo hid the pencil in his closed fist...
>
>   Write, Mo! He pressed the pencil down onto the blood-soaked paper...
>
>   DEATH.*
>   - Chapter 75, The Book, Inkdeath

The only reason for change from the German *Tintenblut* to *Inkspell* that I can find is the assertion of American "squeamishness" at a children's book with the word "blood" in the title. A quick check of the Scholastic Catalog of books with the same Grade Level Equivalent as Inkspell reveals only a couple of books with the word "blood" in the title: *Monster Blood* and *Monster Blood for Breakfast*, both of them from R. L. Stine's *Goosebumps* collection.